# How to align currency symbol to the right

Tags: flutter, dart

I want "1.284,00 AOA" instead of the default "AOA 1.284,00".

```dart
final Function currencyFormat = NumberFormat.currency(
  decimalDigits: 2,
  symbol: 'AOA',
).format('1284'); /// Current: AOA 1.284,00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following code :

```
NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'eu', symbol: 'AOA').format(123456);
```

More examples here : https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-formatting-currency-with-numberformat